# C++ multiple reader/writer lockfree FIFO queue for RISC-V?

Tags: c++, queue, riscv, lock-free, stdatomic

Our company is thinking about switching to a RISC-V based embedded processor. As our application is heavily using the queue as the main interthread communication system it would be nice to implement the *most efficient* solution available.

I'm quite new to this (I know a few things about std::atomics) so I wanted to investigate the progress in this area:

1. Does it even make sense to use `std::atomics` on RISC-V or will it be implemented with a lock underneath anyway?
2. What is the progress and performance of lockless multi reader/writer queues at the moment anyway? Are there *proven* C++ implementations available already?

Our toolchain: ninja - gcc 11.2.0 fork (riscv32-esp-elf-g++.exe)

Comment: Can you add your proposed tool-chain to the question as this might affect any answers.

Comment: Risc-V supports lock-free updates via [LR/SC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional). Whether your toolchain will use those depends on the toolchain.

Comment: There is an entire family of "lock-free" algorithms.  "lockless" isn't one of the names.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm - NBAs are about the guarantee of progress if a given thread is suspended at any point.  You appear to be using it as an alias for "I want performance because locks are bad"?

Comment: Locks are not a victimless crime

Comment: You can answer question #1 yourself with `std::atomic<T>::is_lock_free`

Comment: Every time I saw a MPMC queue used it was the wrong architectural decision. Meaning, I think there are legitimate uses for them but I just never saw one in my professional life.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher In danger of going off topic: Why was it the wrong design decisions? What synchronisation idiom have you settled on?

Comment: Is not the queue, it's the architecture of the system above the queue

Comment: See https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/ Basically, you want only one writer per cache line.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher That makes me worry about our architecture. What was the pain point?

Comment: @ErikEidt That's a given!

Comment: I worked at JPM and I wrote their entire low latency architecture. They had previously a nice MPMC setup but as @ErikEidt mentioned, we arranged things such that they would fit an architecture where you have one writer per queue, basically single-producer-multiple consumers, otherwise cache will kill you. It is 10 cycles against 300 cycles for a read in the worst case. Although this is specific to the x86, that should apply to a RISC-V architecture as well.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher Interesting thanks. But couldn't you have an MPMC queue where you put each item on a seperate cacheline? I thought this is standard in MPMC queues.

Comment: What do you mean "each item"? Each writer?

Comment: @HenriqueBucher Each queue slot

Comment: Well that is not a true MPMC queue, those are SPMC queues in parallel.  A true MPMC queue has one entry point and one exit point. The solution is complex and beautiful from a CS view point but pragmatically unwise.